# Is fingerprint authentication meaningless if the server/client is closed source?

Tags: authentication, authenticated-encryption, signal-protocol

I'm talking about when two chat users want to verify their identities via public key fingerprints.

If the Client app is closed source, and we cannot see what it is doing, isn't the Server able to play "Man in the middle" attack here? Client app would just need to display fake but matching fingerprints to both users, and therefore the fingerprint authentication proves nothing?

Maybe I'm missing something, I hope you guys can help me figure this out.

P.S.
I had this question while examining signal protocol, but I believe it applies universally.

Comment: If you don't trust the client application, why do you consider that it is already safe? It can already send your messages to the server. The Man in the Middle attack should occur in the server-side. So, once you verified the identities, the Man in the Middle attack no more feasible, as long as a new identity is required as in the WhatsApp/Signal case.

Comment: I guess that is a valid point. Client could send my plaintext messages to the server much easier, there is no need for server to play MITM.

Comment: Either way will likely result in getting caught if the app is popular.